# Add column from one .csv to another .csv file using Python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am currently writing a script where I am creating a csv file ('tableau_input.csv') composed both of other csv files columns and columns created by myself. I tried the following code:

```
def make_tableau_file(mp, current_season = 2016):
     # Produces a csv file containing predicted and actual game results for the current season
     # Tableau uses the contents of the file to produce visualization 

     game_data_filename = 'game_data' + str(current_season) + '.csv'
     datetime_filename = 'datetime' + str(current_season) + '.csv'

     with open('tableau_input.csv', 'wb') as writefile:
         tableau_write = csv.writer(writefile)
         tableau_write.writerow(['Visitor_Team', 'V_Team_PTS', 'Home_Team', 'H_Team_PTS', 'True_Result', 'Predicted_Results', 'Confidence', 'Date'])

         with open(game_data_filename, 'rb') as readfile:
             scores = csv.reader(readfile)
             scores.next()

             for score in scores:
                 tableau_content = score[1::]
                 # Append True_Result
                 if int(tableau_content[3]) > int(tableau_content[1]):
                     tableau_content.append(1)
                 else:
                     tableau_content.append(0)
                 # Append 'Predicted_Result' and 'Confidence'
                 prediction_results = mp.make_predictions(tableau_content[0], tableau_content[2])
                 tableau_content += list(prediction_results)

                 tableau_write.writerow(tableau_content)

         with open(datetime_filename, 'rb') as readfile2:
             days = csv.reader(readfile2)
             days.next()

             for day in days:
                 tableau_write.writerow(day)
```

'tableau_input.csv' is the file I am creating. The columns 'Visitor_Team', 'V_Team_PTS', 'Home_Team', 'H_Team_PTS' come from 'game_data_filename'(e.g tableau_content = score[1::]). The columns 'True_Result', 'Predicted_Results', 'Confidence' are columns created in the first for loop. 
So far, everything works but finally I tried to add to the 'Date' column data from the 'datetime_filename' using the same structure as above but when I open my 'tableau_input' file, there is no data in my 'Date' column. Can someone solve this problem?

For info, below are screenshots of csv files respectively for 'game_data_filename' and 'datetime_filename' (nb: datetime values are in datetime format)
[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried using the debugger? Does the file open with content in `readfile2` ? Also, this will presumably write all of the input lines first, and then all the date lines below, don't you want to open both files, append both together and then write them?

Comment: Yes I have content in readfile2 (datetime values) and yes basically the idea is append content of both files in my new csv file 'tableau_input'. I did not realize that. Do you have a way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you have the date line at the bottom of the file?

Comment: Yes my date lines have been appended at the bottom of table and the 'Date' column remains empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to test this as I don't really know what the input should look like, but try something like this:

```
def make_tableau_file(mp, current_season=2016):
    # Produces a csv file containing predicted and actual game results for the current season
    # Tableau uses the contents of the file to produce visualization

    game_data_filename = 'game_data' + str(current_season) + '.csv'
    datetime_filename = 'datetime' + str(current_season) + '.csv'

    with open('tableau_input.csv', 'wb') as writefile:
        tableau_write = csv.writer(writefile)
        tableau_write.writerow(
            ['Visitor_Team', 'V_Team_PTS', 'Home_Team', 'H_Team_PTS', 'True_Result', 'Predicted_Results', 'Confidence', 'Date'])

        with open(game_data_filename, 'rb') as readfile, open(datetime_filename, 'rb') as readfile2:
        scoreReader = csv.reader(readfile)
        scores = [row for row in scoreReader]
        scores = scores[1::]
        daysReader = csv.reader(readfile2)
        days = [day for day in daysReader]
        if(len(scores) != len(days)):
            print("File lengths do not match")
        else:
            for i in range(len(days)):
                tableau_content = scores[i][1::]
                tableau_date = days[i]
                # Append True_Result
                if int(tableau_content[3]) > int(tableau_content[1]):
                    tableau_content.append(1)
                else:
                    tableau_content.append(0)
                # Append 'Predicted_Result' and 'Confidence'
                prediction_results = mp.make_predictions(tableau_content[0], tableau_content[2])
                tableau_content += list(prediction_results)
                tableau_content += tableau_date

                tableau_write.writerow(tableau_content)
```

This combines both of the file reading parts into one.

As per your questions below:

```
scoreReader = csv.reader(readfile)
scores = [row for row in scoreReader]
scores = scores[1::]
```

This uses list comprehension to create a list called `scores`, with every element being one of the rows from `scoreReader`. As `scorereader` is a `generator`, every time we ask it for a row, it spits one out for us, until there are no more.

The second line `scores = scores[1::]` just chops off the first element of the list, as you don't want the header.

For more info try these:

[Generators on Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)
[List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Good luck!

Comment: It sounds good. I tried this but it raises me an "TypeError: object of type '_csv.reader' has no len()"

Comment: I tried to replace "for i in range(limit):" by "for i in scores:" and got rid of "limit" var. But It raises an other 'TypeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute '__getitem__'' pointing at this line: "tableau_content = scores[i][1::]"

Comment: It raises this error because csv.reader() object is not a sequence and we cannot access rows by index.

Comment: @DiamondDogs95 Yep, without knowing what your input data looks like, it is hard to test here. Can you please add a few lines of sample data from each file to the original post?

Comment: You can see the csv files content in my original post. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @DiamondDogs95 Try now :)

Comment: It works :) But for a reason I don't understand, when I run the function it sounds to take a lot of time to generate the 'tableau_input' file, obviously more than before. Do you any explanation for this?

Comment: And just to better understand your script you use list comprehension as variable and then you iterate through the list but what represents for instance the second "row" in your list. My hypotesis is that it is a list, so you iterate for row in "row" in ScoreReader but I'm not sure.